# Retrieve the column name inside the lapply with .SD

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to apply a function to all column in data.table. Hence, I use .SD with lapply. But, inside lapply I cannot retrieve the column of my table.

For instance

```
x = data.table(a=1:10, b=10:1, id=1:5)
x[,lapply(.SD,function(t){t*id}),.SDcols=c(1,2)]
Error in ..FUN(a) : object 'id' not found
```

I do the following:

```
x[,lapply(.SD,function(t){t*x$id}),.SDcols=c(1,2)]
```

Can we do better?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

just remove `.SDcols=c(1,2)`. that removes the third column (`id`)

```
 > x[,lapply(.SD,function(t){t*id})]
     a  b id
 1:  1 10  1
 2:  4 18  4
 3:  9 24  9
 4: 16 28 16
 5: 25 30 25
 6:  6  5  1
 7: 14  8  4
 8: 24  9  9
 9: 36  8 16
10: 50  5 25
```

to not have the `id`, all the following will work:

```
x[,lapply(.SD[,list(a,b)], `*`, id)]

x[,lapply(.SD[,-3], `*`, id)]

x[,lapply(.SD, `*`,id)][, list(a,b)]
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to avoid applying the function on the column i ?

Comment: @Nicolas please check my edit. Small tip, if you mind speed, try always to give your function the most compact structure you can (often it means faster code).

Comment: I like the first of the three alternatives you give, although using `.SD` becomes redundant. I think `x[,lapply(list(a,b), `*`, id)]` is the best solution, and it involves no more typing than using `.SDcols` in the first place.

Comment: Hi, I don't use `SDcols` actually. You're right for this specific case (even though the typing saved is small as well timing difference, but I'd need to check). `lapply` + `.SD` is anyway best practice for data tables with many columns (for obvious reasons).